# How to get exit code of a subprocess?

Tags: windows-10, exit-code, forking

So, I have process B. Typically, process B is called and ran entirely with the context of process A. Unfortunately, for some reason, process B has stopped running properly when called by A, but it does work perfectly when called directly from the command line.

I don't have access to the source for process A unfortunately -- Is there any way I can get the exit code from process B while it is being called by process A? I'm using windows 10 -- Maybe something in the same family as ProcMon?

Comment: Sure add the logic of `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% >> "c:\logs\logfile.txt"`, etc. to the process where applicable and then check the log file after it's run to see what it is.I assume you're talking about a [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) via Windows command line batch, etc.